# Parsing slice information from a slice object?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the information from a slice.  Here's the start of my function. (I have tried "elif isinstance(key, slice):" for the fourth line and can't get that to work)

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key,(int, long)):
        #do stuff if an int
    elif #item is slice
        #do stuff if a slice
```

If I make a function call of obj[4:6] to call this function and I print the "key" variable in the function, it prints "slice(4,6, None)"
How do I parse the 4 and 6 values?  What I"m trying to do is be able to use the data from the list inside the function.

Comment: What is an example of what you would pass in as "key" and what is the expected return?

Comment: the function call is simply obj[4:6] or obj[45].  4:6 being the range of low<=t, t<high.  The return is a list that falls in that range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> slice(4,5).start
4
>>> slice(4,5).stop
5
>>> slice(4,5).step  #None
```

One particularly useful method of the slice object is the `indices` method:

```
>>> slice(4,5).indices(12)
(4, 5, 1)
```

You might use it like this:

```
 for i in range(*my_slice.indices(len(self))):
     print self[i]
```

Note that this really shines with negative indices or steps:

```
>>> slice(4,-5).indices(12)
(4, 7, 1)
>>> print range(*slice(None,None,-1).indices(12))
[11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: oh nice... key.start and key.stop is it!  Thank you!

Comment: @mgilson, is there a way to pass or parse the colon notation for functions taking a slice object as input?

Comment: @alancalvitti -- Nope, that syntax only works inside `[]`.  You could make a hack class `S` whose instances `__getitem__` just returns the slice object that was passed to it.  `foo(s[1:10])`

Comment: @mgilson, thanks. I'd like to use the full generality of colon notation, whereas I think `slice` does not support all the default combos, eg: `list(range(10))[2::3]` or `list(range(10))[::3]`, correct? If so, will the hack class you describe be an effective workaround?

Comment: @mgilson, I see that `None` can be used to emulate the default args in `slice`. However, a class approach might still be a more readable shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the info from the slice object, access its attributes `start`, `stop`, and `step`.  These attributes are documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).